# How can I download this file with wget?

Tags: command-line, downloads, wget

How can I download this file with wget or some other command-line tool?  What's going wrong when I try?

http://ipc.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/Planners?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=seq-opt-base.tar.bz2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
wget -c "http://ipc.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/Planners?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=seq-opt-base.tar.bz2"
```

Note that change `view&target` to `get&target` and quote the link.